# Confused about how Echo filter diagram works

Tags: filters, signal-analysis

[image]

The picture above is the block diagram of an echo filter. My question is, how does the delay, and gain block affect the output signal? I think that when the input signal is outputted with a delay from when the user and a smaller amplitude.

Comment: Can you please edit the question for clarity? The way it stands now, it requires a complete explanation of delay units and their effect on loops which can go on for a while. In the meantime, [are you clear with the basics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_filter) of the type of filter your question is about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the attenuation compensation block the output of your echo filter can be written like: 
 $$output = input + delayed~ input × gain$$The delay block delays your input signal by a specific number of samples and then the delayed signal is multiplied by the gain ($gain<1$  due to losses in the echo path). So you are basically adding a delayed version of your original signal to the original signal.

Answer (score 0):

The output is the sum of the input and a scaled and delayed version of the input

$$y[n] = 2 \cdot (x[n] + 0.8 \cdot x[n-4000])$$

The multiplier of 2 seems a little suspicious. Divide by 2 (or multiply by 0.5) would make more sense.